# Sending Email with codenameOne Message class

Tags: java, email, codenameone

i've followed this example [CodenameOne message Class](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/messaging/Message.html)  but i get getting this exception

```
> java.io.IOException: Failed to open mailto:marwen1609@gmail.com?body=Body%20of%20message&subject=Subject%20of%20message. Error message: Un périphérique attaché au système ne fonctionne pas correctement.

> at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:90)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.mail(WDesktopPeer.java:71)
    at java.awt.Desktop.mail(Desktop.java:474)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.sendMessage(JavaSEPort.java:6667)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.sendMessage(Display.java:3251)
```

please help i didn't find much documentation to go with, here's my code

```
Message m = new Message("Body of message");
m.getAttachments().put("/resources/test.txt", "text/plain");
Display.getInstance().sendMessage(new String[] {"marwen1609@gmail.com"}, "Subject of message", m);
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because JavaSE failed to find a default mail application defined in your system. This will act correctly on the device where the OS native mail app will launch when you invoke that call.

Comment: Guys u have to expand ur documentation seriously !!

Comment: It's more than 1000 pages and very detailed JavaDocs. There is no lack of documentation for this specific API or in this specific instance. Seriously!!!